# Is there a better way to do this in in Quality Center?

Tags: sql, hp-quality-center

Is there a better way to this?I am Trying to extract everything under a specific folder in QC

```
SELECT A.AL_FATHER_ID, A.AL_ITEM_ID, A.AL_DESCRIPTION as Folder
FROM All_LISTS A
where A.AL_DESCRIPTION=@folderName@

union
SELECT B.AL_FATHER_ID, B.AL_ITEM_ID, B.AL_DESCRIPTION as Folder
FROM All_LISTS B
where B.AL_FATHER_ID = (select A.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS A where A.AL_DESCRIPTION=@folderName@)

union
SELECT B.AL_FATHER_ID, B.AL_ITEM_ID, B.AL_DESCRIPTION as Folder
FROM All_LISTS B
where B.AL_FATHER_ID in (select C.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS C where C.AL_FATHER_ID= (select A.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS A where A.AL_DESCRIPTION=@folderName@))

union
SELECT B.AL_FATHER_ID, B.AL_ITEM_ID, B.AL_DESCRIPTION as Folder
FROM All_LISTS B
where B.AL_FATHER_ID in (select D.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS D where D.AL_FATHER_ID in (select C.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS C where C.AL_FATHER_ID= (select A.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS A where A.AL_DESCRIPTION=@folderName@)))

union
SELECT B.AL_FATHER_ID, B.AL_ITEM_ID, B.AL_DESCRIPTION as Folder
FROM All_LISTS B
where B.AL_FATHER_ID in (select E.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS E where E.AL_FATHER_ID in(select D.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS D where D.AL_FATHER_ID in (select C.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS C where C.AL_FATHER_ID= (select A.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS A where A.AL_DESCRIPTION=@folderName@))))

union
SELECT B.AL_FATHER_ID, B.AL_ITEM_ID, B.AL_DESCRIPTION as Folder
FROM All_LISTS B
where B.AL_FATHER_ID in (select F.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS F where F.AL_FATHER_ID in (select E.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS E where E.AL_FATHER_ID in(select D.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS D where D.AL_FATHER_ID in (select C.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS C where C.AL_FATHER_ID= (select A.AL_ITEM_ID from ALL_LISTS A where A.AL_DESCRIPTION=@folderName@)))))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"? What do you mean with "extract everything"? You want to enumerate folders and tests under a root folder? Does is need to be done in SQL, or can you use the QC OTA interface? That one has a NodeByPath () method, returning a node which has a FindTests method. That one returns a list of items under the node. Would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are bound to SQL, you might be in good luck and can `use Oracle 11gR2's recursive subquery factoring clause`, see http://technology.amis.nl/2009/09/01/oracle-rdbms-11gr2-goodbye-connect-by-or-the-end-of-hierarchical-querying-as-we-know-it/.

*Otherwise, you might want to do what you do now in an iterative way.* That won´t make things *simpler*, but *more general* (and *possibly more elegant*) than the solution you posted, because that one is limited to a fixed number of hierarchy levels.